# PHP thinks array is an integer

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, casting, integer

This is the 2nd time this has happened today while coding and it's super frustrating as I don't see what I'm doing wrong

In the code below `$_SESSION['groupData']` is a multi-dimensional array.

```
foreach($_SESSION['groupData'] as $i){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($i);
    echo "<pre>";

    if(in_array($_SESSION['uid'], $i)){

        echo $i['cn'][0];   
    }
}
```

And below is the output of the `$i` (1 **ARRAY** per loop)

```
Array
(
    [cn] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
            [0] => SSO Administrators
        )

    [0] => cn
    [uniquemember] => Array
        (
            [count] => 10
            [0] => u1
            [1] => u2

        )

    [1] => uniquemember
    [count] => 2
    [dn] => cn=blah
)


Array
(
    [cn] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
            [0] => group
        )

    [0] => cn
    [uniquemember] => Array
        (
            [count] => 10
            [0] => u1
            [1] => u2

        )

    [1] => uniquemember
    [count] => 2
    [dn] => cn=blank
)


Array
(
    [cn] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
            [0] => bork
        )

    [0] => cn
    [uniquemember] => Array
        (
            [count] => 10
            [0] => u1
            [1] => u2

        )

    [1] => uniquemember
    [count] => 2
    [dn] => cn=blah
)
```

But then it gives me the error

> "Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer given"

`$i` is an array, is it not? why else would `$i` echo as an array with `print_r($i)`??

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Joe

Comment: None of your numerically keyed values are arrays

Comment: @JohnConde He's not iterating over those arrays, those are the elements of the main array he's iterating over.

Comment: Is this really the whole code? I'll bet you have some additional code that's reusing the `$i` variable.

Comment: Would this matter? should I recast $i as an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried re-initializing $i before looping through it:

```
$i = array();
```

And this did not work. Then I tried type juggling:

```
$j = (array) $i;
```

And this did work. Strange that PHP acts this way.